# ASP.NET MVC annoying bug inside web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I am currently working on an Asp.Net MVC web project. My project is being used on 3 different web servers, each with their own SQL database.  Recently I have been having a very annoying bug that doesn't hurt anything, but wastes my time and is making me pull my hair out.

The issue only occurs when I switch between web servers (ie, when I want to quit publishing to Site A and publish the change to Site B also), or when I **make a change to the web.config** file in my project.

This is a look at how my connection strings are sorted in my web.config. When I need to publish to site or test changes via localhost, I simply just comment the current string, and uncomment the desired choice.

Web.config code (Server C is being user here)

```
<connectionStrings>
<!-- Server A-->
<!--add name="MyEntities" connectionString="******;user id=********;password=**********;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"-->
<!--Server B-->
 <!--add name="MyEntities" connectionString="******;user id=********;password=**********;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"-->
<!--Server C-->
 <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="******;user id=********;password=**********;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
</connectionstrings>
```

If i were to comment out Server C, and then uncomment Server A and build the project, this error would occur:

> BindingRedirect is missing required field 'newVersion'

When I double click and check the error's location it leads me to this line of code:

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.5.0.0" nembnwVersion="5.5.0.0" />
```

***As you can see, "newVersion" somehow was changed to "nembnwVersion = "5.5.0.0""...***

I then have to correct the error and rebuild again. Once rebuilding I get a message saying that my file has been edited, and needs to be reloaded. I reload and the error occurs. This happens every single time I change the web.config or attempt to edit what server I am currently using. How can I stop my web.config to automatically changing "newVersion" to the random string of characters? As i mentioned, its not a project-breaking bug but it sure is very annoying and wastes my time.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered binding redirect do working because of a missing namespace on the `assemblyBinding` element.

**Correct Code:**

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.CompanyValues" publicKeyToken="1a696d1f90f6158a"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.0.3191.28836" newVersion="1.0.3191.28836"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

**Incorrect Code:**

Note missing: `xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"`

```
<assemblyBinding>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="CMS.CompanyValues" publicKeyToken="1a696d1f90f6158a"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.0.3191.28836" newVersion="1.0.3191.28836"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: I checked and sadly already have "xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" in my assembly binding. Thank you for the help though.

Comment: I think you are using `nembnwVersion` instead of `newVersion`.

Comment: in my post as you see `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.0.3191.28836" newVersion="1.0.3191.28836"/>` I am using `newVersion` instead of `nembnwVersion`

Comment: I understand it is incorrect. My problem is that when I publish/change any code in the web.config it automatically changes "newVersion" into "nembnwVersion".

Comment: Try Re-Start your Visual Studio and check again